# Load Data in Modal with Ajax from Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, modal-dialog, fragment, thymeleaf

I just started with Spring two month ago and never did Ajax or JavaScript before. So i'm pretty new to this. What i want to do is load data from a GET Method in my Controller to populate this into a modal. I'm using ajax for this. Basicly i did what this guy https://qtzar.com/2017/03/24/ajax-and-thymeleaf-for-modal-dialogs/ is doing. But it's not working.

Hope somebody can help me with this.

Here is my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/reservations/details/{reservationId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getReservationDetails(@PathVariable("reservationId") String reservationId, Model model, Principal principal, HttpServletRequest request){
    LOGGER.info(LogUtils.getDefaultInfoStringWithPathVariable(request, Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(), " reservationId ", reservationId.toString()));

    User authenticatedUser = (User) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();
    if(authenticatedUser.getAdministratedRestaurant() == null) {
        LOGGER.error(LogUtils.getErrorMessage(request, Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(), "The user " + authenticatedUser.getUsername() + " has no restaurant. A restaurant has to be added before offers can be selected."));
        return null;
    }

    Reservation reservation = reservationRepository.findOne(Integer.parseInt(reservationId));
    if(reservation == null){
        return null;
    }
    List<ReservationOffers> reservationOffers = reservation.getReservation_offers();
    if(reservationOffers == null){
        return null;
    }
    model.addAttribute("offers", reservationOffers);

    return "reservations :: reservationTable";

}
```

This is the button which calls the JavaScript within the "reservation.html"

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" th:onclick="'javascript:openReservationModal(\''+*{reservations[__${stat.index}__].id}+'\');'">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
```

Here is the modal I want to show:

```
    <div id="reservationModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" th:fragment="reservationTable">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" th:text="'Reservation Details'">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-hover" id="reservationTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td th:text="'Name'"></td>
                            <td th:text="'Amount'"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr th:each="offer : ${offers}">
                            <td th:text="${offer.getOffer().getTitle()}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${offer.getAmount()}"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is a empty div in my reservation.html

```
<div id="modalHolder">

</div>
```

And there is the JavaScript with Ajax:

```
<script th:inline="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function openReservationModal(id) {


    $.ajax({
        url: "/reservations/details/"+id,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#modalHolder").html(data);
            $("#reservationModal").modal("show");
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Thank you guys!

EDIT:
Here is the Table which contains the button:

```
<form action="#" th:object="${wrapper}" method="post">
    <div style="height: 190px; overflow: auto;">
        <table class="table table-hover" id="reservationTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th th:text="#{reservations.label.oderId}">Id</th>
                    <th th:text="#{reservations.label.customername}">name</th>
                    <th th:text="#{reservations.label.datetime}">date with time</th>
                    <th th:text="#{reservations.label.price}">price</th>
                    <th th:text="#{reservations.label.donation}">customer donation</th>
                    <th th:text="#{reservations.label.priceWithDonation}">price included with Donation</th>
                    <!-- <th th:text="#{reservations.label.confirmed}">finished reservation</th> -->
                    <!-- <th th:text="#{reservations.label.isfree}">free reservation</th> -->
                    <th th:text="#{reservations.label.choice}">reservation selection</th>
                    <th th:text="#{reservations.label.details}">reservation details</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="reservation, stat: *{reservations}">               
                    <div th:switch="${reservation.isUsedPoints()}">
                        <div th:case="false">
                            <td th:text="${reservation.getReservationNumber()}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${reservation.getUser().getUsername()}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${#dates.format(reservation.reservationTime, 'HH:mm')}"></td> 
                            <td><span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(reservation.getTotalPrice(), 1, 'POINT', 2, 'COMMA')}"> </span> &euro;</td>
                            <td><span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(reservation.getDonation(), 1, 'POINT', 2, 'COMMA')}"> </span> &euro;</td>
                            <td><span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(reservation.getDonation() + reservation.getTotalPrice(), 1, 'POINT', 2, 'COMMA')}"> </span> &euro;</td>
                            <!-- <td th:text="${reservation.isConfirmed()}"></td> -->
                            <!-- <td th:text="${reservation.isUsedPoints()}" ></td> -->
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{reservations[__${stat.index}__].id}" />
                                <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{reservations[__${stat.index}__].confirmed}"/>
                                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{reservations[__${stat.index}__].rejected}" />
                                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{reservations[__${stat.index}__].donation}"/>
                                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{reservations[__${stat.index}__].totalPrice}"/>
                                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{reservations[__${stat.index}__].usedPoints}"/>
                            </td>           
                        </div>
                         <div th:case="true">
                        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{reservations[__${stat.index}__].id}" /> 
                        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{reservations[__${stat.index}__].confirmed}" />
                        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{reservations[__${stat.index}__].rejected}" />  
                        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{reservations[__${stat.index}__].donation}"/>
                        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{reservations[__${stat.index}__].totalPrice}"/>
                        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{reservations[__${stat.index}__].usedPoints}"/>
                    </div>
                    <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" th:onclick="'javascript:openReservationModal(\''+*{reservations[__${stat.index}__].id}+'\');'">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                    </td>
                    </div>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" th:text="#{reservations.button.confirm}" name="confrim" style="float: right; margin-right: 25px;"></button>
        <button type="reject" class="btn btn-success" th:text="#{reservations.button.reject}" name="reject" style="float: right; margin-right: 25px;"></button>
        <input type="hidden"
            th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Have you checked for JS errors in your browser console? What does the AJAX request / response look like?

Comment: Also, can you share an example of the rendered HTML for the following line please? : <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" th:onclick="'javascript:openReservationModal(\''+*{reservations[__${stat.index}__].id}+'\');'">

Comment: I just checked it with the debugger in Firefox and it seems like it doesn't enter the success function at all. But I'm wondering because the modal shows up just without any.

Comment: When you inspect the rendered HTML (via your browser > view source), what does the line of code for the button look like?

Comment: Its:

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" th:onclick="'javascript:openReservationModal('7');'">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>

Answer (score 2):

Okay i found two mistakes by myselfe. First the Table which contians the button had the same id as the modal. The second one was the @ResponseBody Annotation in the controller. Now its returning the right data to the console but still not to the modal.

Here is the output on the console:

```
Data: <div id="reservationModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Reservation Details</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-hover" id="reservationOfferTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>Amount</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Schwarzer Kaffe</td>
                            <td>1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Haxn</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just if somebody is interested, I fixed the problem by moving the empty div "modalHolder" into the form which contains the button.